# invalid path exception in DatabaseFactory.exists()

Tags: blackberry

I am testing sqlite database code in blackberry simulator 5.0 and 6.0. I have created the sdcard for simulators. but sometimes I am getting inavlid path exception on DatabaseFactory.exists() method call.

```
            //URI myURI = URI.create("/Store/Databases/usage.db");
            //URI myURI = URI.create("file:///SDCard/databases/usage.db");
            URI myURI = URI.create("file:///SDCard/usage.db");
            //check if database exists or not

            if ( DatabaseFactory.exists(myURI) )
            {
                d = DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);
            }
            else
            {
                d = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(myURI);        

            }
```

I can see the file "usage.db" in SDCard folder and currently I don't have real device to test this code. am I missing something?

Comment: Have you mounted the directory as the SDCard in your simulator at runtime?

Comment: Hello there i am alos facing the same problem , "Error: invalid path name - path does not contain root list in simulator". while debugging. How to set up the simulator directory path at run time?

Answer (score 0):

@Srizan Sagar: you can set up simulator directory path at run time following this step:

Open this Simulator.

1) click on Simulate then, point to change SDCard.
2) Click on Add directory, browse your SDCard. 
3) Now Select your SDCard in browsing, then select OK.
4) Now Click on Close button.

Your SDCard is simulated now.

@Vivart

Please use path, like this

path="file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/usage.db"